# UIActionSheet not rotating in landscape mode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet and I set it's view like this:

```
[popup showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

this works fine in portrait mode, but when I switch to landscape, it stays portrait. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're showing it in the window (which is not rotated), rather than in a view controller's view (which is). Pass the main view of your currently-visible view controller instead, or use `showFromTabBar:` or `showFromToolbar:` on iPhone or `showFromBarButtonItem:animated:` or `showFromRect:inView:animated:` on iPad.

Comment: Doesn't help if you don't have a toolbar and don't have a tab bar on iphone... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this instead:

```
[popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

[popup showFromToolbar:self.view];

Special for ActionSheet within ActionSheet.